# Using psql, how do you get the total sum for last 3 days, on each day?

Tags: psql

I have a table that contains all purchases made at each school. I’m able to get the total spent per school, per item, per day, 
with the following.

```
SELECT
 date
 school_id,
 item_id, 
 sum(price) as total_price
 FROM purchases
 GROUP BY school_id, item_id, date
 ORDER BY school_id, date
```

It will return something like

```
date         school_id  item_id   total_price
 2016-11-18 |      1   |      1   |        0.50
 2016-11-17 |      1   |      2   |        1.00
 2016-11-16 |      1   |      1   |        0.50
 2016-11-18 |      2   |      2   |        1.00
 2016-11-17 |      2   |      2   |        1.00
 2016-11-16 |      2   |      2   |        1.00
```

I need a table that returns the total price for the last 3 days (including the day of) on each day, 
So something like

```
 date         school_id  item_id   total_price
 2016-11-18 |      1   |      1   |        1.00
 2016-11-17 |      1   |      2   |        1.00
 2016-11-16 |      1   |      1   |        0.50
 2016-11-18 |      2   |      2   |        3.00
 2016-11-17 |      2   |      2   |        2.00
 2016-11-16 |      2   |      2   |        1.00
```

I know I can use lag() OVER (PARTITION BY), but I may need to do this for months at the time instead of 3 days, and lag will take forever to get set up. 
I’m not really sure what other method I can use. Any guidance?

Comment: I don't understand your expected `total_price` column.  Why doesn't `school_id = 1` have a total price of 2 on `2016-11-18` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for looking into this. I really appreciate it! The reason it's a total of 1 is because it's only summing up item_id 1.  School_id 1 for date 2016-11-17 is item_id 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple INNER JOIN would do
You join the table to itself, when the school and item match, and the date is 3 days range

Notice that this would give a moving average of the last 3 days, but it seems so from your question, since you want consecutive days, without jumps

```
SELECT
 p1.date
 p1.school_id,
 p1.item_id, 
 SUM(p2.price) total_price_3_days

purchases p1
INNER JOIN purchases p2 ON p1.school_id = p2.school_id AND p1.item_id = p2.item_id AND p2.`date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(p1.`date`, INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND p1.`date`
 GROUP BY p1.school_id, p1.item_id, p1.date
 ORDER BY p1.school_id, p1.date
```

Comment: I think this is more in mysql perhaps? but I got the point. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to just use a correlated subquery in the select clause:

```
SELECT
    date,
    school_id,
    item_id, 
    (SELECT SUM(p2.price) FROM purchases p2
     WHERE p1.school_id = p2.school_id AND
           p2.date BETWEEN p1.date - INTERVAL '3 DAY' AND p1.date) AS total_price
FROM purchases p1
GROUP BY school_id, item_id, date
ORDER BY school_id, date DESC;
```

### Demo

Another approach would be to take advantage of Postgres' window functions:

```
SELECT
    date,
    school_id,
    item_id, 
    SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY school_id
        ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total_price
FROM purchases p1
GROUP BY school_id, item_id, date
ORDER BY school_id, date DESC;
```

### Demo

Both generate this output:

[image]

Note that my `school_id=1` output does not agree with your expected output, but I think your expected data has a typo.

Comment: I think this is close, but requires a lot of modifications. Thanks for your input!